# mongodb updateOne value in an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

So I have an update one function going i just need to know how to update one of the elements in an array rather than wipe and replace the whole thing.

```
labelRelease = function(db, callback){
    db.collection($$showName).updateOne(
    {'showName' : $$showName},
    {
        $set: {'episode[2]' : data + label}
    }, function(err, results){
        callback();
    });
}
```

Is a stripped down version of the code I am using to update, obviously the `episode[2]` does not work to select only one array element how can i achieve this?

relevant part of the database

```
episode:[episode1, episode2, episode3.....]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update an array element by position by using [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-elements-in-arrays):

```js
labelRelease = function(db, callback){
    db.collection($$showName).updateOne(
        {'showName' : $$showName},
        {
            $set: {'episode.2' : data + label}
        }, 
        function(err, results){
            callback();
        });
};
```

If the index of 2 is in a variable, you need to build up your `$set` value in a couple steps:

```js
var index = 2;
var setValue = {};
setValue['episode.' + index] = data + label;

labelRelease = function(db, callback){
    db.collection($$showName).updateOne(
        {'showName' : $$showName},
        {
            $set: setValue
        }, 
        function(err, results){
            callback();
        });
};
```

Comment: really quick, I assumed I could just go 'episode.' + index:data.... index being equal to two in this case what is the notation for that? cant seem to find it.

Comment: Works like a charm thanks, strange tho how in the case of adding a variable you have to pre generate the entire command, one would think you could just set a variable that is a string and replace just the episode part.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for the set operation is:

```
$set: { 'episode.2' : ... } }
```

Note that episode.2 refers to the 3rd element of the episode array.